# Javascript retornar resultado para Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma pagina com um multselect em jquery ([Link](http://loudev.com/#home)). Nesse multselect existem 2 lista, uma com os todos os calores e outra com os valores selecionados.

Ao editar esse cadastro, seleciona-se os valores que deseja atribuir ao "cliente" e salva.

Meu problema esta justamente aqui, ao salvar eu não consigo receber os dados selecionados nesse multiselect para passar pro meu Controller.

VIEW:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>
                Especialidades
                <small>Especialidades do cliente.</small>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <select id="my-select" multiple='multiple' name="especialidades">


                @foreach (var item in Model.Especialidade_NSelecionada)
                {
                    <option value='@item.idespecialidade'>@item.Nome</option>
                }

                @foreach (var item in Model.Especialidade_Selecionada)
                {
                    <option value='@item.idespecialidade' selected  name="especialidades">@item.Nome</option>

                }

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // run pre selected options
    $('#my-select').multiSelect()
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Editar(Model_Cliente cli)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var id = cli.idcliente.ToString();
            var crm = cli.CRM;
            var nome = cli.Nome;
            var email = cli.Email;
            var aniversario_m = cli.Aniversario_m;
            var endereco = cli.Endereco;
            var num = cli.Num;
            var cidade = cli.Cidade;
            var bairro = cli.Bairro;
            var uf = cli.UF;
            var fone_celular = cli.Fone_Celular;
            var fone1 = cli.Fone1;
            var fone2 = cli.Fone2;
            var contato = cli.Contato;
            var aniversario_c = cli.Aniversario_c;
            var hora_in = cli.Horario_In;
            var hora_out = cli.Horario_Out;
            var obs = cli.Observacoes;
            //aqui esta vindo vazio:
            var especialidades = cli.Especialidade_Selecionada;

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(cli);
    }
```

Eu sou péssimo com java e não tenho a menor ideia de como receber os dados selecionados pelo multiselect, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Imagem de exemplo do multselect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY4aI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tens de guardar os dados num array, depois ou mandas por POST ou XMLHttpRequest, com o seguiente código consegues saber quais são os selecionados:

```
     $('#my-select').multiSelect({
      afterSelect: function(values){
        alert("Valor seleccionado: "+values);
       //Addicionar ao array
      },
      afterDeselect: function(values){
        alert("Valor desselecionado: "+values);
      //Remover do array
      }
    });
```

Comment: Eis o meu problema, não sei fazer um array em javascript e muito menos como passar esse array para o controler.

A pagina envia todas as informaçoes do cadastro para o controller através do HtmlHelper, controller então recebe um model do cliente com as informações, como eu faria pro javascript mandar esse array pro meu controler junto com as outras informações?